# Retrieve Result from Hyperledger Fabric Transaction

Tags: javascript, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I submitted a transaction to Hyperledger Fabric, but I'd like to get object created by this.

The object that I get from this is `Undefined`.
Obs: The transaction is successfully created in Hyperledger Fabric.

```
async submit(resource, method) {
    try{
      this.businessNetworkDefinition = await this.bizNetworkConnection.connect(cardname);
      if (!this.businessNetworkDefinition) {
        console.log("Error in network connection");
        throw "Error in network connection";
      }

      let factory        = this.businessNetworkDefinition.getFactory();
      let transaction    = factory.newTransaction(NS, method);

      Object.assign(transaction, resource)
      return await this.bizNetworkConnection.submitTransaction(transaction);
    }catch(error){
      console.log(error);
      throw error;
    }
  }
```

Comment: see examples https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/reference/js_scripts The 'return` type of the trxn is always a Promise - the developer can resolve the type, based on his knowledge or the type it is returning. Eg. returns a Promise using `exists` function  which can be resolved as a Boolean, having value either true or false. Similarly if calling REST API endpoints from the REST API (transaction submitted). The TP returns a Promise which can be resolved as a Boolean, having value either true or false - depending on the result.

Comment: you will also get the `transactionId` returned after submission and you can access the transaction object by querying the transaction class (in the transaction class registry)  once its been committed.

Comment: @PaulO'Mahony, I am not getting `transactionId` in the return. However I didnt like to do a query to get the object. It was suppose to return something in transaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently the submitTransaction function is not returning anything. It is a bug or working as intended.

To go into more detail: When you delve through the source code of the composer you will finally get to the following code in composer-connector-hlfv1.

```
invokeChainCode(securityContext, functionName, args, options) {
        const method = 'invokeChainCode';
        LOG.entry(method, securityContext, functionName, args, options);

        if (!this.businessNetworkIdentifier) {
            return Promise.reject(new Error('No business network has been specified for this connection'));
        }

        // Check that a valid security context has been specified.
        HLFUtil.securityCheck(securityContext);

        // Validate all the arguments.
        if (!functionName) {
            return Promise.reject(new Error('functionName not specified'));
        } else if (!Array.isArray(args)) {
            return Promise.reject(new Error('args not specified'));
        }

        try {
            args.forEach((arg) => {
                if (typeof arg !== 'string') {
                    throw new Error('invalid arg specified: ' + arg);
                }
            });
        } catch(error) {
            return Promise.reject(error);
        }

        let txId = this._validateTxId(options);

        let eventHandler;

        // initialize the channel if it hasn't been initialized already otherwise verification will fail.
        LOG.debug(method, 'loading channel configuration');
        return this._initializeChannel()
            .then(() => {

                // check the event hubs and reconnect if possible. Do it here as the connection attempts are asynchronous
                this._checkEventhubs();

                // Submit the transaction to the endorsers.
                const request = {
                    chaincodeId: this.businessNetworkIdentifier,
                    txId: txId,
                    fcn: functionName,
                    args: args
                };
                return this.channel.sendTransactionProposal(request); // node sdk will target all peers on the channel that are endorsingPeer
            })
            .then((results) => {
                // Validate the endorsement results.
                LOG.debug(method, `Received ${results.length} result(s) from invoking the composer runtime chaincode`, results);
                const proposalResponses = results[0];
                let {validResponses} = this._validatePeerResponses(proposalResponses, true);

                // Submit the endorsed transaction to the primary orderers.
                const proposal = results[1];
                const header = results[2];

                // check that we have a Chaincode listener setup and ready.
                this._checkCCListener();
                eventHandler = HLFConnection.createTxEventHandler(this.eventHubs, txId.getTransactionID(), this.commitTimeout);
                eventHandler.startListening();
                return this.channel.sendTransaction({
                    proposalResponses: validResponses,
                    proposal: proposal,
                    header: header
                });
            })
            .then((response) => {
                // If the transaction was successful, wait for it to be committed.
                LOG.debug(method, 'Received response from orderer', response);

                if (response.status !== 'SUCCESS') {
                    eventHandler.cancelListening();
                    throw new Error(`Failed to send peer responses for transaction '${txId.getTransactionID()}' to orderer. Response status '${response.status}'`);
                }
                return eventHandler.waitForEvents();
            })
            .then(() => {
                LOG.exit(method);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                const newError = new Error('Error trying invoke business network. ' + error);
                LOG.error(method, newError);
                throw newError;
            });
    }
```

As you can see at the end, all that is happening is waiting for Events and Log.exit which return nothing.  So currently you have to get your transaction result in another way.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I could get something from my chaincode is through events. There's native interface that might be able to query for transaction data or something like this, but i haven't looked into it yet.

Comment: For me, event doesnt work and I didnt like to make a query to get the transaction that I just did. Every database retrieves the object created as response.

Comment: Well, Fabric is not a database. And no blockchain lets you get the object you added in the same transaction.